# Javascript in D365, set required filed

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365

I have a requirement to set visible and set required field on chosing one option. I am able to set visible but not able to setRequiredLevel in client API.

```
if(selectedItemCurrent != null && selectedItemCurrent.includes(8))
                {
                     formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(true);
                     formContext.getControl("comments").setRequiredLevel("required");
                 } else
                 {
                     formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(false);
                     formContext.getControl("comments").setRequiredLevel("none");
                 }
                
            }
```

Or

```
formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(selectedItemCurrent?.includes(8)&&setRequiredLevel("required"));
```

Both are throwing exception. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: What is the message of the exception? Also, make sure the schema name `comments` of your field is right, usually there need to be some prefix for custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you can get the *visible* to work, so I assume the column name is correct. Please try using the getAttribute function instead of getControl when setting the requiredLevel

You can also do something like this:

```
let isVisible = (selectedItemCurrent != null && selectedItemCurrent.includes(8));

formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(isVisible);
formContext.getAttribute("comments").setRequiredLevel(isVisible ? "required" : "none");
```

I am copying the documentation links for both methods.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/attributes/setrequiredlevel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/setvisible

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

> This works for me

```
if(selectedItemCurrent != null && selectedItemCurrent.includes(8))
           {
           formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(true);
           formContext.getAttribute("comments").setRequiredLevel("required");
           } else
                 {
                     formContext.getControl("comments").setVisible(false);
                     formContext.getAttribute("comments").setRequiredLevel("none");
                 }
                
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).